# Is there a way to eliminate duplicate 'point clusters' in SQL Server 2008 r2 spatial?

Tags: sql-server, geometry, pointgeometry

I am using the ST.Distance function to identify clusters of geometry data points.  Each point has a unique reference number associated with it.  I would like to eliminate duplicate clusters from the output, as it is very likely that within my dataset 2 different 'clusters' could contain the exact same 6 (or more) data points.  Is there a way to do this?

My SQL to identify the clusters is basically as follows:

```sql
declare @radius as float = 50
SELECT t1.ref,
SUM (CASE WHEN t1.geolocation.STDistance(t2.Geolocation) <= @radius 
          THEN 1 Else 0 End)      
FROM DataTable as t1, DataTable as t2  
WHERE [t1].[ref] != [t2].[ref] 
GROUP BY [t1].[ref]
HAVING SUM (CASE WHEN t1.geolocation.STDistance(t2.Geolocation) <= @radius 
          THEN 1 Else 0 End) >5

ORDER BY [t1].[ref]
```

Comment: So, you would count it as a cluster if there are six points within 50m of each other and all of their geometries are the same, ie, each of the six (or more) points. Or is it enough that six, or more, points be within 50m of each other?

Comment: It would count as a cluster if 6 or more points are within 50m, but i do _not_ want to return clusters where the 6 points have identical geometries to those in a different cluster that has already been identified.  Ideally, if another cluster had the same 6 points but also additional ones, I would only return the biggest cluster (but i think that may be another step beyond the initial query)